# Wordpress custom SELECT query for alphabetical index

Tags: wordpress, indexing

I'm trying to make an alphabetical index with wordpress, so far I've managed to get the $letter parameter and make the query, but I can't sort the results by a specific category_name, here's my code:

global $wpdb;

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results(
        "
        SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
        WHERE post_title LIKE '$letter%'
        AND post_type = 'directory'
        AND category_name = 'company'; 
        "
);
```

Everything works just fine untill the query gets to the category_name, I checked the Wordpress Codex but I didn't get it very well.

I would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: I didn't get your question. `ORDER BY post_title` ?

Comment: You can use this way http://geekgirllife.com/alphabetical-index-of-posts-in-wordpress/

Comment: $letter = A, so I'm trying to get all posts with the title starting with "A", that works fine, then I want them to be of the post type "directory", that works fine too, but then I want them to be on the category name 'company' and that doesn't work. I think I have to do a inner joun but I'm not very good with inner joins, so I'm stuck in this part. (Sorry about my english, it's not my first language)